# Could Etherscan read data for a Dapp?

Tags: blockchain, ethereum

If blockchain like Ethereum is a public blockchain, wouldn't all my data for my Dapp can be seen by all using something like Etherscan?

Answer (score 1):

It's a public blockchain, so yes, everything is visible. Every address balance, contract bytecode, transaction data, contract state, etc. is visible. You can encrypt data before sending it to the blockchain, but that makes it difficult to do anything useful within a transaction.

If you need privacy, consider using a private blockchain.